# When am writing the messages into a kafka topic using spark streaming it is just writing into one partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

How to make spark write messages into all the partitions in the kafka so that I can use a directstream and improve the performance of the streaming.

here is my code:-

```
object kafka {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FlightawareSparkApp")
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(3))
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 18436)
                        val topic = "test"
                        val props = new java.util.Properties()
                        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "list")
                        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "list")
                        //  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                        // props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                        props.put("client.id", "KafkaProducer")
                        props.put("producer.type", "async")
                        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer")
                        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
                rdd.foreachPartition(part => {
                    val producer = new KafkaProducer[Integer, String](props)
                    part.foreach(msg =>{
                        val record = new ProducerRecord[Integer, String](topic, msg)
                        producer.send(record)
                    })
                    producer.close()
                })
            })
            ssc.start()
            ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

}

this code is pushing messages into kafka topic but when I see the count using

```
 /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $KAFKABROKERS --topic test --time -1
```

am getting output where I can see the messages only in one partition.

```
test:8:0
test:2:0
test:5:0
test:4:0
test:7:0
test:1:0
test:9:0
test:3:0
test:6:237629
test:0:0
```

Any suggestions on how to split the data into all the partitions.

How to implement partition key by default in the program in order to distribute the messages across the partitions.

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't set the key. You can find the following details in Kafka FAQ [1].

> Why is data not evenly distributed among partitions when a partitioning key is not specified?
>
> In Kafka producer, a partition key can be specified to indicate the destination partition of the message. By default, a hashing-based partitioner is used to determine the partition id given the key, and people can use customized partitioners also.
>
> To reduce # of open sockets, in 0.8.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1017), when the partitioning key is not specified or null, a producer will pick a random partition and stick to it for some time (default is 10 mins) before switching to another one. So, if there are fewer producers than partitions, at a given point of time, some partitions may not receive any data. To alleviate this problem, one can either reduce the metadata refresh interval or specify a message key and a customized random partitioner. For more detail see this thread http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201310.mbox/%3CCAFbh0Q0aVh%2Bvqxfy7H-%2BMnRFBt6BnyoZk1LWBoMspwSmTqUKMg%40mail.gmail.com%3E

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ

Comment: Thank You for the reply.  IF I pass any random key here then will it work. val record = new ProducerRecord[Integer, String](topic,key,8, msg).